# Vectorize glm and extract all information

Tags: r, vectorization, glm, tapply

I have a data set "keywords" with several groups.  I want to apply glm to each group individually to create a list of glm fits with one fit for each group.

I could do this with a **for** loop, but thats not in the R spirit.  Instead, I tried to do it with a **by** function:

```
CTR.glm <- by(keywords,keywordsInSample,
          function(x) ifelse(nlevels(factor(x$AveragePosition))>20, # only these keywords will be fit
                             glm(Clicks ~ poly(log(AveragePosition),2) + offset(log(Impressions)),
                                 family = poisson,data = x),
                             NA)) # for functions that can't be fit
```

The problem is that whereas **glm** normally returns a glm-class object from which I can extract all sorts of goodies, **by** returns a list

```
> CTR.glm[2]
$`text of second keyword`
               (Intercept) poly(log(AveragePosition), 2)1 poly(log(AveragePosition), 2)2 
                 -3.626237                      -5.108795                      -1.751032 
> class(CTR.glm[2])
[1] "list"
```

All information has been lost except for the parameters of the fit.  Is there a way to force by to keep all the information about the list?

p.s., I tried using the **plyr** toolbox, but it got stuck because my keywords have spaces in them.

p.p.s., this post should have the tag "by", but I can't create that tag (new to stackoverflow), could someone retag it?

Comment: Can you edit to tell us what `keywords` and `keywords in sample` look like?

Comment: how about `lme4:::lmList` with `family` set?

Comment: Other options aside, there is absolutely **nothing** wrong with using a `for()` loop in R. The issues with loops were largely something inherent to S, not R. Yes, they can be inefficient if a vectorised (truly vectorised, at the C level) alternative exists or if you fail to allocate storage before the loop, but if there isn't and you do, loops can be highly effective & easy to read/understand compared to some of the other options. Yes, you have to manage the bookkeeping yourself, but that is usually trivial.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
lapply(CTR.glm,summary)
```

The list probably contains model objects, which still have the information you need

Answer (score 0):

I think `plyr` should work just fine. I don't know the structure of your `keywords` and `keywordsInSample`, but consider that this toy example works fine:

```
require(plyr)
#generate some fake data, with a factor whose names have spaces in them
l <- c(rep("a a", 3), rep("a", 3), rep("b b", 3))
x <- rep(1:3, 3)
y <- rnorm(9)
d <- data.frame(keywordsInSample=grp, x=x, y=y)

lmList <- dlply(d, .(keywordsInSample), function(df) glm(df$y~df$x))
lmList$"a a"
```

As long as your index variable can be forced into a factor, R will internally represent it as numeric levels, and shouldn't care about what the names of the levels contain.